# How to avoid automatic rounding in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I prevent that pandas makes rounding? This is kind of weird because I was coding yesterday and it didn't happen.

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    1:[1,2,3,4,5],
    2:[1,2,3,4,5]
}
i = ['A','B','C','D','E']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=i)

print(df)
```

I should get something like this:

```
   1  2
A  1  1
B  2  2
C  3  3
D  4  4
E  5  5
```

Instead:

```
   1     2
A  1.0  1.00
B  2.0  2.00
C  3.0  3.00
D  4.0  4.00
E  5.0  5.00
```

Obviously this is a simplified code, but it's kind of weird because in some columns gets rounded by 2, and others rounded by 1.

BTW, I don't want to disable in all the data frame because I want other columns be rounded.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Nope, I got the integer dataframe from your code/data.

Comment: I got only ints from your dataset. If it worked fine yesterday then you should restart your kernel or wherever you are working and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `astype` and set to `int`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    1:[1,2,3,4,5],
    2:[1,2,3,4,5]
}
i = ['A','B','C','D','E']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=i).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   1  2
A  1  1
B  2  2
C  3  3
D  4  4
E  5  5
```

Answer (score 0):

set the datatype to int or int64. have a look here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html
you can set the types using `dtypes` for yhe entire table or with `astype` for a column.